# Transition height stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GybENz

I've created a simple stacked bar chart with a legend to filter the chart.

I'd like to animated the height of the bar from the bottom axis up.

Currently its animating from the left and down

```
let layersBar = layersBarArea.selectAll('.layer').data(stackedSeries)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'layer')
    .style('fill', (d, i) => {
        return colors[i];
    });

layersBar.selectAll('rect')
    .data((d) => {
        return d
    })

    .enter()
    .append('rect')

    .attr('height', 100)
    .transition()
    .duration(400)
    .attr('height', (d, i) => {
        return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
    })

    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('y', (d) => {
        return y(d[1]);
    })

    .attr('x', (d, i) => {
        return x(d.data.date)
    })

    .attr('width', x.bandwidth());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `x` position, the `width`, the `y` position (as the baseline) and the height (as zero) **before** the transition:

```
.attr('height', 0)
.attr("y", h - margin.bottom - margin.top)
.attr('x', (d, i) => {
    return x(d.data.date)
})
.attr('width', x.bandwidth())
```

Here is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypdoMK?editors=0010

**PS**: It would be a good idea transitioning each rectangle individually. For instance, if the user clicked `usedInf`, you should transition only those rectangles... however, since you did this...

```
layersBarArea.selectAll('g.layer').remove();
```

... at the beginning of your `drawChart` function, which is a wrong approach, such suggestion will need a big refactor, out of the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Can you explain why `layersBarArea.selectAll('g.layer').remove();` is the wrong approach. Is this an option or will it cause me problems. I did ask how to approach this in another question but got not response

Comment: The whole logic of the enter/exit/update selection is updating the chart. However, you're erasing everything and repainting everything each time the function runs!

Comment: So will my approach break or it just not as goos as it could be. What is best to do this, what question do I ask

Comment: This is not a *question*. This involves knowing how to create those selections in D3. Unfortunately, you cannot ask for a tutorial here at Stack Overflow. I suggest you check some books on D3 or other resources, searching for "enter/exit/update selections". And yes, your approach is not good, and it will fail in several situations.

Comment: So are you saying its a better approach to draw the bar chart then just change the y height of the rectangles that I want to filter out

Comment: Yes, the y position and the height.